# JSONDecodeError at /pro/product/5/

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

whenever i run the server at localhost i got this error
cant figure out what the issue is 
here is the code of the request

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def ProductView(request,id):
    # status = get_object_or_404(id=request.POST.get('id', ''))
    stat = get_object_or_404(Product,id=id)

    serializer =ProductSerializer
        # serializer = serializers.statusSerializer(stat,many=True)
    nice=stat.name
    # nice = str(stat.total)
    print(nice)
    # return Response(json.loads(reade r(nice)))
    return Response(json.loads(nice))
```

this the error

```
JSONDecodeError at /pro/product/5/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: "levis"  name that belongs to that id

Comment: yes,when i run "return Response(nice) " i just get the string  printed

Comment: cool issue has been solved

Comment: what is the role of serializer in your view

Answer (score 0):

As you are using DRF, then you can take the advantage of using its own [seralization](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/). So you can try like this:

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def ProductView(request,id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        stat = get_object_or_404(Product,id=id)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(stat)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           serailizer.save()  # Save data if you need or ommit it.
           return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
           return Response({'error': True})
```